# Geoserver How to call existing functions inside new WPS process

Tags: geoserver, geotools, wps

I am pretty new to Geoserver and programming processes for it. I having trouble to find the information I need.
Is it possible to call a existing function inside my own WPS class? I want to clip some polygons but don't want to import the whole clipping sourcecode into my project.
Do I need some special imports or is it possible to access other WPS processes directly? Would be some sort of process chaining I guess. I can only find examples for this using the WPS builder and XML files but I don't want to go this way, insted do this directly in Java.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly easy to call a GeoTools process from within your code:

```
Name name = new NameImpl("TableJoin", "joinTables");
org.geotools.process.Process process = Processors.createProcess(name);

ProcessExecutor engine = Processors.newProcessExecutor(2);

// quick map of inputs
String sname = statesDS.getTypeNames()[0];
String iname = stateUnempDS.getTypeNames()[0];
String typeName = statesDS.getSchema(sname).getTypeName();
Join j = new Join(typeName, ECQL.toFilter("strToLowerCase(\"A.STATE_NAME\") = strToLowerCase(\"STATE_NAME\")"));
j.setAlias("A");
QueryType query = Wfs20Factory.eINSTANCE.createQueryType();
query.getTypeNames().add(sname);

query.setFilter(j.getJoinFilter());
query.getAliases().add("A");

WFSConfiguration configuration = new org.geotools.wfs.v2_0.WFSConfiguration();
org.geotools.xml.Encoder encoder = new org.geotools.xml.Encoder(configuration);

// create an output stream
ByteArrayOutputStream xml = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// encode
encoder.encode(query, org.geotools.wfs.v2_0.WFS.Query, xml);

String jxml = xml.toString("UTF-8");
xml.close();
System.out.println(jxml);
Map<String, Object> input = new KVP("target", statesDS.getFeatureSource(sname).getFeatures(), "source",
    stateUnempDS.getFeatureSource(iname).getFeatures(), "join", jxml);

Progress working = engine.submit(process, input);

Map<String, Object> result = working.get(); // get is BLOCKING
SimpleFeatureCollection out = (SimpleFeatureCollection) result.get("result");
```

Don't worry too much about the XML encoding of the query element that is just if you need to pass an XML string in. Most processes are more likely to take a `featureCollection` and a few primitives. The easiest way to see how to call an existing process is to check out it's test class.